# how to get console in scilab 6.1.0 from ubuntu LTS 20.04 terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 20.04, scilab

P.S: (1)although scilab can be accessed through command "scilab cli"
&  (2) I recently upgraded OS from LTS 18.04 to 20.04.
but cannot find the console anymore.

Comment: By console, did you mean the GUI? I thought you were asking how to open the CLI interface. If it the GUI does not show up, does it show any error when you run `scilab` in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missed a hyphen. The command is `scilab-cli`.

Comment: Yup, its scilab-cli. Still the console  is not popping on screen!                                                                Is there any other way ?